# Remove case sensitivity from FormsAuthentication.Authenticate of user name/password

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, forms-authentication

The below code and the config works fine, but force to enter user name/password case sensitively, i want to make it non case sensitive.

Code:

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string uid = UserText.Text.Trim();
                string pwd= PwdText.Text.Trim();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uid) ||
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(pwd))
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("UserName or Password should not be blank.");
                }

                bool isAuthrnticated = FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(uid, pwd);

                if (isAuthrnticated)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("Admin", false);

                    //...
                }
                else
                {
                    ((Site)this.Master).ShowError("Invalid UserName/Password.", ErrorSeverity.Warning);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLogger.LogError(ex);
                ((Site)this.Master).ShowError(ex.Message, ErrorSeverity.Warning);
            }
        }
```

Web.Config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" loginUrl="~/Default.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="1000">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="Admin" password="ZAdmin"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, usernames are not case sensetive and passwords are. The easiest way to do this is when they register, change both un and pw to either ToUpper() or ToLower() and then when you are authenticating, do the same to whatever they enter.

```
string uid = UserText.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
string pwd= PwdText.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you store the username and password, instead of storing them as-is, call ToUpper() on them first. Then do the same thing to the strings you pass in to FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(). That way, both will have been converted to all-uppercase versions before comparing, rendering case irrelevant.

Comment: that is the manual way of doing this, is there any configuration for this, so that no need to change the code?

Answer (score 0):

Set collations of your database so you do not need to keep track of case sensitivity
http://web.archive.org/web/20080811231016/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-can-i-make-my-sql-queries-case-sensitive.html

Comment: i am not using sql server at all. username and password is stored on the web.config file itself, and i am using the Asp.Net FormsAuthentication.